# Share image and text and url in whatsapp

Tags: swift

I have tried the following code but only text and url is shared. I have used UIActivityItemSource also but this uses either text or image. Is there any work around to achieve these?

```
var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()
objectsToShare.append(self.postTitle!)
objectsToShare.append(self.postUrl!)
objectsToShare.append(self.postImage!)

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]
presentationContext.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```